# neo4j apoc.cypher.run - cannot get to work - says syntax error but really is authentication?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have documented an annoying situation over here:
https://neo4j-users.slack.com/archives/C1APWRTRU/p1528192526000108

I started to appear yesterday, I think. Previously it worked fine.

Comment: If you have a question, please add it in full here. Referencing on another system (in this case Slack), while that can be an addition, should not take the place of the actual question or question details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to Mac representation of new line. The text was copy pasted from Excel on Mac, and contained CR for new line. Changed to LF, and it works.